# eigenvalues with column summing to c

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a $n \times n$ matrix A, the columns sum to a real value $c$. How do I show that $c$ is an eigenvalue of the Matrix.

My attempt, I can see that the matrix $A-cI$ has columns summing to $0$, why would that mean that $A-cI=0$ in general for the condition to be satisfied?

Comment: Is it *one* column sum to $0$ or *all* columns sum to$0$? The first case is obviously false, e.g. $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0$1\end{pmatrix}$. The second column sum to $2$, but $2$ is not an eigenvalue.

Comment: all the columns sum to $c$ for A. And hence all the columns of $A-cI$ sum to $0$

Comment: What does the matrix do to the column vector all of whose entries are 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be matrix such that$$\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}=c\quad\forall i\tag{1}$$
We now need to prove $det (A-cI)=0$. To prove this, let's sum all the lines in $A-cI$. Then for all $i$ and for all $j$, we have
$$\sum_{j\neq i}a_{ij}+a_{ii}-c$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} -c$$
By equation $(1)$
$$c-c=0$$
Since we now have a line of $0$, the determinant is $0$
$$det (A-cI)=0$$
and $c$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix is similar to its transpose. For the matrix $A$,we see that  $A^T$ has all rows adding to $c.$Thus if $v$ is the $n-$place column vector with all entries equal to 1, then $$A^Tv=cv$$, so $c$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T$. Since similar matrices have the same eigenvalues and $A$ is simiar to $A^T$ , $c$ is also an eigenvalue of $A.$